# Autocomplete list from JSON file with criteria

Tags: android, json, authentication

Can someone point me to right direction, how to create an adapter for AutoCompleteTextView, which would be getting data from JSON file on the intenet, using data, which user entered into the text field? I want to use the user-entered data to filter suggestions for autocompletion. I imagine that adapter should always take user-entered data as soon as changes appears and use it for fetching suggestions on-the-fly. Is that possible? So far I've seen many tutorials for autocompletion where static String arrays were used, but never seen them build dynamically. Is it possible to do it automatically or I need always fetch String array myself and pass as ArrayList to adapter on every AutoCompleteTextView change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ArrayAdapter` can take in a mutable `List`.  You should be able to get the entries from anywhere you like, it doesn't need to be a static array.

To change the entries at runtime, just update the list and call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on the `ArrayAdapter` to let it know that it should look for changes.